# Not working javascript codes when rotating page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a javascript file which I used it for making a carousel in my website. But I want to make it responsive. So, I changed it. When you refresh page, it works well but when you rotate the page in mobile or tablet it could not match itself by new width and height. what is the problem?

```js
$(".website_carousel").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".nexts",
   btnPrev: ".prev",
 visible:(($(window).width() > 481) ? "3" : "2")
})
```

here is the plugin I used for carousel

```js
(function ($) {                                          // Compliant with jquery.noConflict()
    $.jCarouselLite = {
        version: '1.1'
    };

    $.fn.jCarouselLite = function(options) {

        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.jCarouselLite.options, options || {});

        return this.each(function() {   // Returns the element collection. Chainable.

            var running,
                animCss, sizeCss,
                div = $(this), ul, initialLi, li,
                liSize, ulSize, divSize,
                numVisible, initialItemLength, itemLength, calculatedTo, autoTimeout;

            initVariables();                    // Set the above variables after initial calculations
            initStyles();                       // Set the appropriate styles for the carousel div, ul and li
            initSizes();                        // Set appropriate sizes for the carousel div, ul and li
            attachEventHandlers();              // Attach event handlers for carousel to respond

            function go(to) {
                if(!running) {
                    clearTimeout(autoTimeout);  // Prevents multiple clicks while auto-scrolling - edge case
                    calculatedTo = to;

                    if(options.beforeStart) {   // Call the beforeStart() callback
                        options.beforeStart.call(this, visibleItems());
                    }

                    if(options.circular) {      // If circular, and "to" is going OOB, adjust it
                        adjustOobForCircular(to);
                    } else {                    // If non-circular and "to" is going OOB, adjust it.
                        adjustOobForNonCircular(to);
                    }                           // If neither overrides "calculatedTo", we are not in edge cases.

                    animateToPosition({         // Animate carousel item to position based on calculated values.
                        start: function() {
                            running = true;
                        },
                        done: function() {
                            if(options.afterEnd) {
                                options.afterEnd.call(this, visibleItems());
                            }
                            if(options.auto) {
                                setupAutoScroll();
                            }
                            running = false;
                        }
                    });

                    if(!options.circular) {     // Enabling / Disabling buttons is applicable in non-circular mode only.
                        disableOrEnableButtons();
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }

            function initVariables() {
                running = false;
                animCss = options.vertical ? "top" : "left";
                sizeCss = options.vertical ? "height" : "width";
                ul = div.find(">ul");
                initialLi = ul.find(">li");
                initialItemLength = initialLi.size();

                // To avoid a scenario where number of items is just 1 and visible is 3 for example.
                numVisible = initialItemLength < options.visible ? initialItemLength : options.visible;

                if(options.circular) {
                    var $lastItemSet = initialLi.slice(initialItemLength-numVisible).clone();
                    var $firstItemSet = initialLi.slice(0,numVisible).clone();

                    ul.prepend($lastItemSet)        // Prepend the lis with final items so that the user can click the back button to start with
                        .append($firstItemSet);     // Append the lis with first items so that the user can click the next button even after reaching the end

                    options.start += numVisible;    // Since we have a few artificial lis in the front, we will have to move the pointer to point to the real first item
                }

                li = $("li", ul);
                itemLength = li.size();
                calculatedTo = options.start;
            }

            function initStyles() {
                div.css("visibility", "visible");   // If the div was set to hidden in CSS, make it visible now

                li.css({
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    "float": options.vertical ? "none" : "left" // Some minification tools fail if "" is not used
                });

                ul.css({
                    margin: "0",
                    padding: "0",
                    position: "relative",
                    "list-style": "none",
                    "z-index": "1"
                });

                div.css({
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    position: "relative",
                    "z-index": "2",
                });

                // For a non-circular carousel, if the start is 0 and btnPrev is supplied, disable the prev button
                if(!options.circular && options.btnPrev && options.start == 0) {
                    $(options.btnPrev).addClass("disabled");
                }
            }

            function initSizes() {
    var width_1 = div.width();
    width_2=width_1/numVisible;
    li.css({'width':width_2+'px'});
                liSize = options.vertical ?         // Full li size(incl margin)-Used for animation and to set ulSize
                    li.outerHeight(true) :
                    width_2;
                ulSize = liSize * itemLength;       // size of full ul(total length, not just for the visible items)

                // Size of the entire UL. Including hidden and visible elements
                // Will include LI's (width + padding + border + margin) * itemLength - Using outerwidth(true)
                ul.css(sizeCss, ulSize+"px")
                    .css(animCss, -(calculatedTo * liSize));

                // Width of the DIV. Only the width of the visible elements
                // Will include LI's (width + padding + border + margin) * numVisible - Using outerwidth(true)

            }

            function attachEventHandlers() {
                if(options.btnPrev) {
                    $(options.btnPrev).click(function() {
                        return go(calculatedTo - options.scroll);
                    });
                }

                if(options.btnNext) {
                    $(options.btnNext).click(function() {
                        return go(calculatedTo + options.scroll);
                    });
                }

                if(options.btnGo) {
                    $.each(options.btnGo, function(i, val) {
                        $(val).click(function() {
                            return go(options.circular ? numVisible + i : i);
                        });
                    });
                }

                if(options.mouseWheel && div.mousewheel) {
                    div.mousewheel(function(e, d) {
                        return d > 0 ?
                            go(calculatedTo - options.scroll) :
                            go(calculatedTo + options.scroll);
                    });
                }

                if(options.auto) {
                    setupAutoScroll();
                }
            }

            function setupAutoScroll() {
                autoTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    go(calculatedTo + options.scroll);
                }, options.auto);
            }

            function visibleItems() {
                return li.slice(calculatedTo).slice(0,numVisible);
            }

            function adjustOobForCircular(to) {
                var newPosition;

                // If first, then goto last
                if(to <= options.start - numVisible - 1) {
                    newPosition = to + initialItemLength + options.scroll;
                    ul.css(animCss, -(newPosition * liSize) + "px");
                    calculatedTo = newPosition - options.scroll;

                    console.log("Before - Positioned at: " + newPosition + " and Moving to: " + calculatedTo);
                }

                // If last, then goto first
                else if(to >= itemLength - numVisible + 1) {
                    newPosition = to - initialItemLength - options.scroll;
                    ul.css(animCss, -(newPosition * liSize) + "px");
                    calculatedTo = newPosition + options.scroll;

                    console.log("After - Positioned at: " + newPosition + " and Moving to: " + calculatedTo);
                }
            }

            function adjustOobForNonCircular(to) {
                // If user clicks "prev" and tries to go before the first element, reset it to first element.
                if(to < 0) {
                    calculatedTo = 0;
                }
                // If "to" is greater than the max index that we can use to show another set of elements
                // it means that we will have to reset "to" to a smallest possible index that can show it
                else if(to > itemLength - numVisible) {
                    calculatedTo = itemLength - numVisible;
                }

                console.log("Item Length: " + itemLength + "; " +
                    "To: " + to + "; " +
                    "CalculatedTo: " + calculatedTo + "; " +
                    "Num Visible: " + numVisible);
            }

            function disableOrEnableButtons() {
                $(options.btnPrev + "," + options.btnNext).removeClass("disabled");
                $( (calculatedTo-options.scroll<0 && options.btnPrev)
                    ||
                    (calculatedTo+options.scroll > itemLength-numVisible && options.btnNext)
                    ||
                    []
                ).addClass("disabled");
            }

            function animateToPosition(animationOptions) {
                running = true;

                ul.animate(
                    animCss == "left" ?
                    { left: -(calculatedTo*liSize) } :
                    { top: -(calculatedTo*liSize) },

                    $.extend({
                        duration: options.speed,
                        easing: options.easing
                    }, animationOptions)
                );
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.jCarouselLite.options = {
        btnPrev: null,              // CSS Selector for the previous button
        btnNext: null,              // CSS Selector for the next button
        btnGo: null,                // CSS Selector for the go button
        mouseWheel: false,          // Set "true" if you want the carousel scrolled using mouse wheel
        auto: null,                 // Set to a numeric value (800) in millis. Time period between auto scrolls

        speed: 200,                 // Set to a numeric value in millis. Speed of scroll
        easing: null,               // Set to easing (bounceout) to specify the animation easing

        vertical: false,            // Set to "true" to make the carousel scroll vertically
        circular: true,             // Set to "true" to make it an infinite carousel
        visible: 3,                 // Set to a numeric value to specify the number of visible elements at a time
        start: 0,                   // Set to a numeric value to specify which item to start from
        scroll: 1,                  // Set to a numeric value to specify how many items to scroll for one scroll event

        beforeStart: null,          // Set to a function to receive a callback before every scroll start
        afterEnd: null              // Set to a function to receive a callback after every scroll end
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: your settings will apply once, on initialization, you have to `LISTEN` for window size changes and then apply the new params

Comment: the problem is, when you load the page, some Li created in Ul and when you rotate the page based on the plugin file, some new Li's created whitout deleting old ones. So, width of Ul become twice and it caused disfunctioned. How can I eliminate Li's when I rotate the page?

Comment: have you read the docs of this plugin?

Comment: yes, but I changed the plugin and make it responsive. Originally it is not responsive, So docs of the plugin is not mentioned about making responsive.

Comment: have you a link to the plugin page? Is it not the same as I mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The jquery library may be not working.Make sure you did include javascript Jquery library is correctly.

Comment: It is included well because other jquary codes work correctly

Comment: if you want to get screen width and height, use screen.availHeight and screen.availWidth or if you want to display some div in certain width or height use @media (max-width:your value){} css property

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation:
https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite#responsive-carousels

> ## Responsive Carousels
>
> The responsive option is set to `false` by default. Once you set it to
>   `true`, you may want to set a few other options to get the desired
>   effect:
>
> Everything automatic (autoCSS is true by default, so no need to add
>   it)
>
> ```
> $('div.carousel').jCarouselLite({
>   // autoCSS: true,
>   autoWidth: true,
>   responsive: true
> });
> ```
>
> Everything manual (autoWidth is false by default, so no need to add
>   it)
>
> Your best bet in this situation is to use CSS media queries.
>
> ```
> $('div.carousel').jCarouselLite({
>   autoCSS: false,
>   // autoWidth: false,
>   responsive: true
> });
> ```
>
> // Bind your own handler to the `refreshCarousel` custom event, //
>   which is triggered when the window stops resizing
>
> ```
> $('div.carousel').on('refreshCarousel', function() {
>   // do something
> });
> ```